# Error trying to change contents of string pointer in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I'm working on a program in C and one of my key functions is defined as follows:

```
void changeIndex(char* current_index)
{
    char temp_index[41]; // note: same size as current_index
    // do stuff with temp_index (inserting characters and such)
    current_index = temp_index;
}
```

However, this function has no effect on `current_index`. I thought I found a fix and tried changing the last line to

```
strcpy(current_index, temp_index)
```

but this gave me yet another error. Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong here? I basically just want to set the contents of `current_index` equal to that of `temp_index` at each call of `changeIndex`.

If more information is needed, please let me know.

Comment: If you have a pointer to a string literal (`char *data = "example";`) make it const to have the compiler warn you about illegal changes to the literal: `const char *data = "example";` **attempting to change a string literal causes Undefined Behaviour**

Comment: "*but this gave me yet another error.*" which one please?

Comment: Please give more complete code. Problem is often elsewhere than what you think (like if this is because you try to modify string literal, it's impossible to know if included code does not show it).

Comment: @pmg -- this code is for a class and we are not allowed to change that

Comment: Homework problems are a bit problematic at SO, because including your code on a public internet site can lead to problems... However, this is no excuse for incomplete question.

Comment: When I tried doing it the `strcpy` method, I got

`Bus error: 10`

Comment: What do you pass into the changeIndex function?

Comment: In C, argument passing is by value. So changing a formal does not affect the caller.

Comment: You need to clarify whether you are dealing with strings or not. (A string is a series of characters followed by a null character to indicate the end of the string).  A buffer of characters without a null terminator is not a string.

Answer (score 1):

`strcpy` should work if `current_index` points to allocated memory of sufficient size. Consider the following example, where `changeIndex` require additional parameter - size of distination string:

```cpp
void changeIndex(char* current_index, int max_length)
{
    // check the destination memory
    if(current_index == NULL)
    {
        return; // do nothing
    }
    char temp_index[41]; 
    // do stuff with temp_index (inserting characters and such)

    // copy to external memory, that should be allocated
    strncpy(current_index, temp_index, max_length-1);
    current_index[max_length-1] = '\0';
}
```

Note: `strncpy` is better for the case when `temp_index` is longer then `current_index`.

Examples of usage:

```cpp
    // example with automatic memory
    char str[20];
    changeIndex(str, 20);
    // example with dinamic memory
    char * ptr = (char *) malloc(50);
    changeIndex(ptr, 50);
```

Answer (score -1):

Obviously defining a local char array on the stack and returning a pointer to it is wrong. You should never do that as the memory is not defined after the function ends.

In addition to the previous answers: The strncpy char pointer (which seems unsafe for my opinion), and the malloc which is safer but you need to remember to free it outside of the function (and its inconsistent with the hierarchy of the program) you can do the following:

```
char* changeIndex()
{
    static char temp_index[41]; // note: same size as current_index
    // do stuff with temp_index (inserting characters and such)
    return temp_index;
}
```

As the char array is static it will not be undefined at the end of the function and you do not need to remember to free the pointer at the end of the use.

Caveat: If you are using multiple thread you cannot use this option as the static memory could be changed by different threads entering the function at the same time

Comment: The function is supposed to write to the buffer pointed to by  `current_index`

Comment: Not necessarily. The author of the question asked why his implementation doesn't work, his question was answered (as I stated in my answer). I offered another solution to his problem. Sometimes it is better to broaden the limits of the conversation so that people could learn out of it.

Answer (score -3):

Your array `temp_index` is local for function, then `*current_index` don't take what u want.

U can use also function `strdup` . Function return begin memory location of copied string , or `NULL` if error occurred, lets say ( `char *strdup(char *)` )

```
char temp[] = "fruit";
  char *line = strdup(temp );
```

Comment: Bad suggestion to allocate memory which will not be freed.

Comment: So how u think to pass temp_index to unmalloced space? That cause UB. He maybe need current_index to use in other function, and then there he can to free that string.

Comment: Just do think about how current_index is passed. I believe you will be able to understand that he cannot free the memory malloc()-ed inside of changeIndex.